# How to add OG to the menu?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have Organic Groups installed within Drupal 7 and I am attempting to get the groups to display in the menu. For all authenticated users I want the group(s) they belong to show up in the menu (could be the user menu).

**Addition:**

The picture below shows how far I have gotten. This is within the edit view window. The closest window shoes the fields that can be added. The only group-specific fields I found are `Group: Group permissions` and `Group: Group user roles` and for the filter there aren't any group-specific choices. Is there some roundabout way to add them or a specific permission I may be missing. I have given my administrator (currently logged in) all of the permissions listed for the groups.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need this in an existing menu?

Personally I would do this with Views. If you have it installed try the below.

1. Create a new view
2. Add a Block Display
3. Set Access to Authenticated Users
4. Change the Basic Settings > Style to "Table"
5. Add Fields for Node Title & Organic Group Post count
6. Add Filters for Organic Group Member "True"

This will now display a table with the titles and a "new" post count. You can make it look more like a traditional menu by changing the view settings further.

Comment: Hi Westie. I was able to do the first 3 steps but I have no idea how to do steps 4, 5 and 6. Do you need any special modules installed? I have OG and Views. Also to what do I add the fields to (the block or view) and how. And where can I access and add the filter? Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Hi @Kyra , In the view you have created you will have all the options above. It is a bit difficult as there is a wall of options. What I do is press ctrl + f and type in "style" for example so the browser highlights it. Providing you have the appropriate permissions set it will be there, no addtional modules required :)

Comment: Hi @Westie. I was finally able to find how to edit the view. The view already shows the node title by default; however, when I go to add fields or add filters I am unable to find the organic group post count or the organic group member to true from the list. Is there a specific permission I am missing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I just updated my views module on a local Drupal 7 install. The UI for views has changed a great deal. I noticed before the update I had several og views by default. These have all gone now and I too dont have the options for og in fields or filters. I suggest you report it on views / og issues queue